# Is there a way to load data from an IQueryable into a Combobox without looping?

Tags: c#, combobox, iqueryable

Basically I have an IQueryable of data that I wish to bind a string (for display) and an int (for data selected) into a combobox so the user can select the appropriate choice. Normally I would just create the combobox, and then loop through the IQueryable adding items to the combobox. But it occurred to me that there might be a way to do this without looping.

Answer (score 2):

set the `ComboBox` `DataSource` to the object.

Comment: Strongly recommend adding .ToList() when binding to a control. The IQueryable must be in scope of the DataContext or ObjectContext when it runs the query. If you simply assign an IQueryable to the control's data source, you don't know that this will be true.

Comment: @drdwilcox Ok cool, how do inform the ComboBox which string and int from the DataSource are to be used? In short, how will it know which ones?

Comment: The `ComboBox` has 2 properties, `DataTextField` and `DataValueField`. Don't forgetto call `DataBind()` after setting the `DataSource`

Comment: @drdwilcox That must be why it's not loading up, however there is no DataBind() method for System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox to be found!

Comment: @drdwilcox also.. it was DisplayMember and ValueMember, not DataTextField and DataValueField... I wonder if we are talking about the same control here?

Comment: I mis-read your question. You are correct that you don't DataBind.

Comment: @drdwilcox So then I wonder why this isn't working? Nothing is showing up in the boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a [Windows Forms ComboBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.aspx)? You could use [AddRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection.addrange.aspx):

```
combobox.BeginUpdate();
combobox.DisplayMember = "Name";
combobox.Items.AddRange(myQueryable.Select(q => new { q.Id, q.Name }));
combobox.EndUpdate();
```

to create anonymous objects storing the ID and name. It may be easier to just work with your original object, though, and cut out the .Select.

Comment: I am going to try this because the other thing isn't working, do you know what would I do if instead I had a List<T>?

Comment: Also this is odd, when I get your code working, despite setting the DisplayMember to the string I want, the combobox is only being filled with the names of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Which technology do you mean (WPF, HTML, WinForms)?
Variant for WPF is:

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsQueriable}"/>

I assume this combo is bound to model like this:

```
 class SomeViewModel {

      public IQuriable<SomeEntity> ItemsQueriable { get; private set; }

 }
```

But, actually I think it is better to bind your items controls to IList<> instead of IQueriable<>, you can use .ToList() extension method to convert